# How can I update Data in Event Hub Microsoft Azure

Tags: c#, azure, azure-eventhub

I'm new in Microsoft Azure
I need to Update Data in Event Hub Microsoft Azure
this my code to send Data in Event Hub :

```
        // Parameter
        string eventHubName = "";
        string eventHubNamespace = "";
        string sharedAccessPolicyName = "";
        string sharedAccessPolicyKey = "";


        //Bus initialization Service
        var settings = new MessagingFactorySettings()
        {
            TokenProvider = TokenProvider.CreateSharedAccessSignatureTokenProvider(sharedAccessPolicyName, sharedAccessPolicyKey),
            TransportType = TransportType.Amqp
        };

        var factory = MessagingFactory.Create(ServiceBusEnvironment.CreateServiceUri("sb", eventHubNamespace, ""), settings);
        EventHubClient client = factory.CreateEventHubClient(eventHubName);

        contact obj = new contact();
        obj.IdC = 12;
        obj.DateContact = DateTime.Now;

        // Serialize to JSON
        var serializedString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);

        EventData data = new EventData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(serializedString))
        {
            PartitionKey = obj.IdC.ToString()
        };

        // Send the event data to an Event Hub
        client.SendAsync(data);
```

Can I do that ?
help me.
thanks.

Comment: I don't think yes/no questions are really helpful here. I mean... couldn't you just run the code on your own and answer your own question? Also: questions such as "why isn't my code working?" are off-topic. And this seems like that type of question (that is, if you ran it and it worked, you wouldn't' be posting here, so does that mean it doesn't work and you're asking for debugging help?).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do what your code is intending to do.

If your question is that if you could update/change a EventData that is already sent/posted to EventHub, then the answer is no.

Comment: This seems better served as a comment, especially given the question isn't a programming question per se - it's something the OP can test on their own.  There's no clear question (aside from "will this work").